# Django django-cms reverse 'NoReverseMatch at..' multisite language

Tags: python, django, django-cms

This seems to be a "classic" problem :

> NoReverseMatch at /tr/showroom/
>   Reverse for 'project-list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

But the problem is, when I check the different topic on the internet and then my files, I don't get it.

So it's working perfectly on the native language. It happens when I try to change the language on this showroom page only.
Every page that have been copy with the commad cms copy works fine except this one.

Well, here is the model :

```
    def get_slug(self):
    return self.safe_translation_getter(
        'slug',
        language_code=get_language(),
        any_language=False)

def get_absolute_url(self, current_app=None):
    """
    Warning: Due to the use of django application instance namespace
    (for handle multi instance of an application)we add the possibility
    to use it with the reverse.
    So if get_absolute_url is call without app instance it may failed (
    for example in django_admin)
    """
    lang = get_language()
    if self.has_translation(lang):
        kwargs = {'slug': self.get_slug()}
        return reverse('djangocms_showroom:project-detail',
                       kwargs=kwargs,
                       current_app=current_app)
    return reverse('djangocms_showroom:project-list', current_app=current_app)

def get_full_url(self, site_id=None):
    return self._make_full_url(self.get_absolute_url(), site_id)

def _make_full_url(self, url, site_id=None):
    if site_id is None:
        site = Site.objects.get_current()
    else:
        site = Site.objects.get(pk=site_id)

    return get_full_url(url, site)
```

The url :

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from .views import (ProjectListView, ProjectDetailView)


urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', ProjectListView.as_view(), name='project-list'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<slug>\w[-\w]*)/$', ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='project-detail'),
)
```

And the html error :

> Error during template rendering

In template /var/www/webapps/blippar_website/app/blippar/templates/djangocms_showroom/project_list.html, error at line 14

Which is :

```
<form id="projects-filter" action="{% url 'djangocms_showroom:project-list' %}">
```

Well, I am not very good yet with django and django-cms, if someone has any clue, it would be marvellous !

Comment: Error message is clear, _error at line 14_ in your template project_list.html which one is line 14?

Comment: From the URL patterns you have shown, there is no regex matching `/tr/....` Can you show the correct url patterns ?

Comment: yes this is the plugin's url pattern.
The `/en/` or `/tr/` or `/es/` must be managed by django-cms.
When I write `url(r'^$'..` -  it means `https://domain.com/lang/`